# Chain of CompletableFutures in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am new to this `CompletableFuture` function in Java. I have the following code below that works fine but looks quite messy IMHO.

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(isRQMRunning_3);

if(cf.isDone()) {
    System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
    cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(startRQM_4);

    if(cf.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
        cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pendingChangesStatus);

        if(cf.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());                   
            cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(acceptPendingChanges_8);

            if(cf.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());                       
                cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(loadWorkspace_5);

                if(cf.isDone()) {
                    System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
                    cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(acceptPendingChanges_8);

                    if(cf.isDone()) {
                        System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
                        cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(fixConflicts_9);

                        if(cf.isDone()) {
                            System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Is it possible to make that look a lot nicer/easier to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of repetition in your code.
The only thing different with the 2 lines of code repeated over and over is the argument.

You could put all of these arguments into a list and iterate over them, running those 2 lines of code for each:

```
List<String> states = Arrays.asList(isRQMRunning_3, startRQM_4, 
  pendingChangesStatus, acceptPendingChanges_8, 
 loadWorkspace_5, acceptPendingChanges_8, fixConflicts_9);

for (String state : states)
{
    // Loop until array is complete
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(state);

    if (!cf.isDone())
    {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Value- " + cf.get());
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion @dustytrash! However, i am in need of also including the **batDir** with each.

Comment: would it just need to be this **CompletableFuture.completedFuture(steps(state, batDir));**?

Comment: Also, should **if (!cf.isDone()) {** be **if (cf.isDone()) {**? If its done then break out, right?

Comment: @StealthRT no, if it's done you want to continue. You stop once isDone returns false. What I wrote should do the exact same thing your code does.